# Question on the history of h aspiré

Tags: phonétique

This is what I found on Wikipedia for *h aspiré*:

> One part of the major phonological changes between Latin and Early Old
>   French was the loss of the consonant /h/, which would later return
>   with the introduction of Germanic words into the language. **The
>   aspirate h ceased to be pronounced once more in either the 16th or the
>   17th century**, but some grammarians kept insisting for it be pronounced
>   into the early part of the twentieth century.

Now, I checked the book that was cited as a reference but didn't manage to find the answer to the question as to *why* did the French stop pronouncing the *h* sound? 
Also does the bolded part mean that those words which are today pronounced with h aspiré were then pronounced with h muet?

Merci d'avance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse the fact an *h* is "aspirated" or not, and the fact an *h* is pronounced or not.

Even when not pronounced like in standard modern French, the aspirated *h* still exists because of its side effects.

For example *homme* has a non aspirated *h* so is pronounced exactly like if written *omme* thus *un homme* is almost pronounced like "*un nomme*", because of the liaison.

There is such an *h* in the English *hour* (**An** hour); compare with *house* (**A** house).

In *house*, the *h* is voiced as a consonant. This consonant no more exists<sup>1</sup> in French.  When the *h* is aspirated, it just prevents the liaison to be realized:

*Un héros* is pronounced like "*un éro*", never "*un néro*".

> Why did the French stop pronouncing the h sound?

I guess because dropping it was a simplification that wasn't breaking the comprehensibility.

> Does the bolded part mean that those words which are today pronounced with h aspiré were then pronounced with h muet?

No, that means aspirated h ceased again to be voiced.

---

See also: [How can we distinguish "H-muet" or "H-aspiré"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1833/how-can-we-distinguish-h-muet-or-h-aspir%C3%A9/8700#8700) and [Understanding an extract on h-aspiré](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32596/understanding-an-extract-on-h-aspir%C3%A9/32597#32597)

<sup>1</sup><sub>We still pronounce the *h* sound in a small set of words. See the linked questions.</sub>